# VeeValidate 'required_if:' rule

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I have used syntax rule `required_if` from docs:
[vee-validate required_if rule](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#required-if) and it doesn't work.

Can someone point me to the right direction?
I need this simple required_if rule to work before I go further.

JSfiddle:

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      first: '',
      last: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll()
        .then(result => {
          console.log(this)
          alert(result)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://unpkg.com/semantic-ui-css@2.2.9/semantic.css');
span.error {
  color: #9F3A38;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.0-beta.25"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form class="ui form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="field" :class="{error: errors.has('first')}">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input ref="firstName" type="text" name="first" placeholder="first" v-model="first">
      <span class="error" v-if="errors.has('first')">{{errors.first('first')}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="field" :class="{error: errors.has('last')}">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="last" v-validate="'required_if:firstName,test'" v-model="last">
      <span class="error" v-if="errors.has('last')">{{errors.first('last')}}</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="ui submit button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you want that last input to be validate as 'required',  if first input has a value already?

Comment: you are using the beta version. Try a stable version to see if that fixes this.

Comment: It did I got it working under this example ;-) 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/2jx2v734pr?fontsize=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Randy Casburn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9078341/randy-casburn) pointed me right - thanks man!

The trouble was with versions. I got it working under this example:
[my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/2jx2v734pr?fontsize=14)

Hope it helps somebody ;-)