# Conditionals in v-form

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm fairly new to vue.js. I'm trying to apply some validations to the text fields. Here's what the form looks like.

[image]

I need to apply some conditionals so that if a user enters the Source IP but does not enter destination IP, the Destination Port is required, however if the user enters the Source IP and Destination IP, the Destination Port is not required. Is it possible?

Code:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-card class="ma-3 pa-3">
      <v-card-title primary-title>
        <div class="headline primary--text">Firewall Logs</div>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
          <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" lazy-validation>
            <v-text-field
                label="Source IP"
                v-model="sourceip"
                v-validate="'required_if|ip'"
                data-vv-name="sourceip"
                :error-messages="errors.collect('sourceip')"
                required
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
                label="Destination IP"
                v-model="destinationip"
                v-validate="'required_if: '"
                data-vv-name="destinationip"
                :error-messages="errors.collect('destinationip')"
                required
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
                label="Destination Port"
                v-model="destinationport"
                v-validate="{  regex: /^(\*[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$/}"
                data-vv-name="destinationport"
                hint="Enter port number between 0 and 65535 or '*' if port is unknown"
                :error-messages="errors.collect('destinationport')"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-select
                item-value="string"
                v-model="day"
                :items="days"
                label="Days To Search"
                hint="Go back up to 7 days to expand the query"
                v-on:change="reset"
            ></v-select>
          </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn small color="error" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn small color="warning" @click="reset">Reset</v-btn>
        <v-btn small color="success" @click="submit" :disabled="!valid">
          Submit
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: v-validate required_if looks promising I just don't know how to properly implement it

Comment: I'd recommend not using such an old version of [Vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3#installation) unless you absolutely have to. In 3^ they've removed the ```v-validate``` and everything is wrapped inside a ```ValidationProvider``` now. You can still make use of ```required_if```

Comment: Also, looks like someone had the same query as you! Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143852/veevalidate-required-if-rule) help you out?

Comment: I’ll take a look and see, thanks!